# Squid not forwarding client IP in reverse-proxy mode

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I am using Squid 3.1.10 (latest version for CentOS 6.4) as a reverse-proxy for a webserver hosting virtual domains. I cannot get Squid to pass the client IP to the webserver, no matter what I try. I have tried setting forwarded_for and the XFF header at different values but all I keep seeing is Squid's ip in apache's access log...even if I set forwarded_for to "delete".

Would someone mind looking over my config, pls?

```
http_port 80 accel vhost

visible_hostname xxx.xxx.xxx

forwarded_for on

shutdown_lifetime 5 seconds

acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1

acl localnet src xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24   # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines


http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

acl Safe_ports port 80 443
http_access deny !Safe_ports

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

acl Safe_proto proto HTTP SSL
http_access deny !Safe_proto


################# BEGIN MAIN SERVER ########################

cache_peer xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=mainwebserver 
acl mainwebserver_cached_sites dstdomain .site1.com .site2.com

http_access allow mainwebserver_cached_sites

cache_peer_access mainwebserver allow mainwebserver_cached_sites
cache_peer_access mainwebserver deny all


################### END MAIN SERVER ########################


hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid


# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

http_access deny all
```

Comment: I have upgraded to Squid 3.4. The few changes brought in by the new config file still leaves me with the same problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The ip was being forwarded, it was apache on that wasn't using it for logging purposes. Simply installing mod_rpaf for apache did the trick.